# Server push technology with mqsql and php

Tags: php, javascript

I found that there are a lot of ways to implement real time web apps. I had a basic knowledge about the AJAX polling technique, but I am looking at an alternative technology called the `HTTP PUSH SERVER`. I've seen a lot of blog posts on the internet, but it doesn't seem to be suited for what I need. The Polling technique is good too but I have a little bit of doubt about it, is it stressful for the server? The polling technique needs to send a request every second with basic JavaScript `setInterval()`.

Is there anyone who can give me a basic idea or some sample code for the `HTTP SERVER PUSH`?

I want to deal with basic client notification when an SQL table changes.

Thanks. Regards

Comment: Did you look into Web Sockets yet?

Comment: No not yet. I think web socket works only with higher version of browser

Comment: If you are really thinking about a polling interval of _one second_, then you are doing it wrong from the very beginning already.

Comment: @BruceElenoisMcGravy Websockets work with all major modern browsers, and there are workarounds for older browsers, like this: http://goo.gl/4wyg0. Check caniuse.com for browser support information: http://caniuse.com/websockets

Comment: If you want to build awesome web apps, then you should know your audience. If someone uses a browser so old that it doesn't support web sockets, then I wouldn't consider that person a part of my audience. Simple as that.